# SSIS package generates blank excel file when executed from SQL Job

Tags: ssis, sql-job

I have an SSIS package that simply exports a database field into a excel file. When I run it in BIDS OR SSMS it outputs perfectly however when I run it from an SQL Job it only creates an empty excel file.

Comment: what do you mean `SQL Job`? SQL server agent ?

Comment: When I schedule a job in SQL server agent.

Answer (score 0):

If your `SQL server agent` get the package from `Integration Service Catalog`, make sure the deployed package has every task enabled, or you could enable the certain importing task and deploy again to the server. Sometimes the deployed package has disabled tasks which may not noticed by the one who deploy the package.

If you use `file system`, also make sure certain task has been enabled.

**More important**, make sure that you are using the **UNC path** for tasks getting access to that file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am using UNC path for tasks. And also all tasks are enabled.